# "go out for a movie" what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I'd like to know what is meant by "go out for a movie". Does it mean "go to a cinema to see a movie", or does it mean "go out to buy/rent a movie"?

If you ask me "What are you doing tonight?", and I reply by saying "I'm going out for a movie tonight.", how would you understand my statement?

Comment: It could be either. Context will determine how it's understood

Answer (score 1):

In the US, at least, "go out for a movie" almost certainly means "**going to [go] see/watch a movie** [in a theater]," which would be the default description. In addition to "I'm going to go out for a movie," one might informally say, "I'm going to go catch a movie." ([Compare via Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watch+a+movie%2Ccatch+a+movie%2Csee+a+movie%2Cgo+out+for+a+movie&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwatch%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatch%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csee%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20out%20for%20a%20movie%3B%2Cc0).)

Before around 2015, it might possibly have meant "**going to [go] rent/get a movie.**" With the spread of streaming online entertainment, however, I think the latter custom has because obsolete (again, in the US).

Nowadays, I would definitely conclude that you're going to watch a movie in a theater.